# Infinite cube and divisible sums

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given is an infinite cube, extended infinitely in all directions. Is it possible to place each positive integer exactly once, so that for any positive integer $n$, the sum of the numbers in any $n\times n\times n$ cube is divisible by $n$?

The condition is trivial when $n=1$, but already gets interesting for $n=2$. If we only care about $n=2$, it should not be hard by iterative construction to make sure that the sum of any $2\times 2\times 2$ cube is even. The difficulty comes in because of higher $n$. For values of $n$ that are coprime (such as $2$ and $3$), it may be helpful to use the Chinese Remainder Theorem, though it is unclear how we would maintain the requirement that every positive integer gets used exactly once.

Comment: for $n=3$ the number of values that are 1 mod 3, 2 mod 3 have to have a difference in quantity divisible by 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give an inductive construction -- sorry this turned out to be a long answer, I probably included too many details. The main idea is that since we're in three dimensions (in fact this works for any number of dimensions $\geq 2$), the constraints are actually not so restrictive, so there's enough freedom to insert whatever numbers are missing as we go.

Let's say a labelling of the points in $C_n := \{0, \dots, n-1\}^3$ (i.e. a function $C_n \to \mathbb{N}$) is *$k$-good* if the sum of the numbers in each $k \times k \times k$ subcube is divisible by $k$, and say that the labelling is *good* if it is $k$-good for each $1 \leq k \leq n$. Note that by the CRT, to show a labelling is good, it suffices to show that it's $k$-good for all prime power $k$ in this range.

Similarly say that a labelling $C_n \to \mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$ is *$p^\ell$-good* (where $\ell \leq k$) if the same condition holds, and is *good* if it is $p^\ell$-good for $1 \leq \ell \leq k$. Then it follows that $f : C_n \to \mathbb{N}$ is good if and only if $f$ mod $q$ is good for each maximal prime power $q \leq n$ (where $q = p^k$ is maximal if $p^{k+1} > n$).

We will show the following:

**Proposition.** Given a good labelling $f : C_n \to \mathbb{N}$ with all labels distinct, such that $\{1, \dots, n\}$ appear as labels, we can extend $f$ to a good labelling $f' : C_{n+1} \to \mathbb{N}$ with all labels distinct, such that $\{1, \dots, n+1\}$ appear as labels.

*Step 1*: For each prime $p \leq n+1$, extend $f$ mod $p$ to a $p$-good labelling $f_p : C_{n+1} \to \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

For a candidate $f_p$ extending $f$ mod $p$, since $f$ is $p$-good the only constraints we need to check are that 
$$\sum_{y \in C_p} f_p(x - y) \equiv 0 \text{ (mod $p$)}$$
for each $x = (x_1, x_2, x_3) \in C_{n+1} \setminus C_n$ with $x_1, x_2, x_3 \geq p-1$. Each such constraint uniquely determines $f_p(x)$ for such an $x$ in terms of $f_p(x')$ for $x'$ with $x_1' + x_2' + x_3' < x_1 + x_2 + x_3$. It follows that we are free to set the values of $f_p(x)$ for those $x \in C_{n+1} \setminus C_n$ with some $x_i < p-1$ (particularly $x = (n, 0, 0)$), and $f_p(x)$ will be uniquely determined for the other points $x \in C_{n+1} \setminus C_n$.

*Step 2*: If $p^k$ is not maximal, given a good labelling $f_{p^k} : C_{n+1} \to \mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$ which extends $f$ mod $p^k$, find a good labelling $f_{p^{k+1}} : C_{n+1} \to \mathbb{Z}/p^{k+1}\mathbb{Z}$ extending $f$ mod $p^{k+1}$.

We will take a candidate $f_{p^{k+1}}$ extending $f$ mod $p^{k+1}$ which agrees with $f_{p^k}$ mod $p^k$. Then using $f_{p^k}$ to denote the corresponding function $C_{n+1} \to \{0, \dots, p^k-1\}$, we can write $f_{p^{k+1}}(x) = f_{p^k}(x) + p^k g(x)$, for some $g : C_{n+1} \to \{0, \dots, p-1\}$. Note that $g(x)$ is determined for $x \in C_n$ since we assumed that $f_{p^{k+1}}$ extends $f$. We know that $f_{p^{k+1}}$ is $p^\ell$-good for $\ell \leq k$, since we assumed that $f_{p^k}$ was good. Thus we only need to check that it is $p^{k+1}$-good, and since $f$ was $p^{k+1}$-good, the only constraints to check are that 
$$\sum_{y \in C_{p^{k+1}}} g(x - y) \equiv - \frac{1}{p^k} \sum_{y \in C_{p^{k+1}}} f_{p^k}(x - y) \text{ (mod $p$)}$$
for each $x = (x_1, x_2, x_3) \in C_{n+1} \setminus C_n$ with $x_1, x_2, x_3 \geq p^{k+1}-1$. Similar to the argument in step 1, we are free to choose the values of $g(x)$ for $x \in C_{n+1} \setminus C_n$ with some $x_i < p^{k+1} - 1$ (including $x = (n, 0, 0)$), and $g(x)$ is uniquely determined on the rest of $C_{n+1} \setminus C_n$.

*Step 3*: Given $f_q$ for all maximal prime powers $q \leq n+1$, construct an extension $f'$ of $f$ to $C_{n+1}$ which agrees with each $f_q$ mod $q$.

For a candidate $f'$ agreeing with $f$ on $C_n$, the only constraints are that $f'(x) \equiv f_q(x)$ (mod $q$) for all $x \in C_{n+1} \setminus C_n$ and maximal $q$. By the CRT, these constraints indeed admit solutions, and in particular, since they only determine $f'(x)$ modulo some large factor, we can choose these labels $f'(x)$ so that all labels are distinct. If $n+1$ was already a label appearing in $f$, then any such choice of $f'$ will do. In the case where $n+1$ did not appear, then since in steps 1 and 2 we could freely set each $f_{p^k}(n, 0, 0)$, we can ensure that each $f_q(n, 0, 0) \equiv n+1$ (mod $q$), in order to label $f'(n, 0, 0) = n+1$. Since $f_q = f'$ mod $q$ is good for each $q$, $f'$ is good, and so it satisfies all of our conditions.

Iteratively extending the initial labelling $f(0, 0, 0) = 1$, we get the desired labelling of $\{0, 1, 2, \dots\}^3$, which includes each positive number exactly once. If you wanted a labelling of $\mathbb{Z}^3$, that can also be done by instead using the domain cubes $\cdots \subset \{-n, \dots, n\}^3 \subset \{-n, \dots, n+1\}^3 \subset \{-n-1, \dots, n+1\}^3 \subset \cdots$.